# How to move a row in a dataframe based on a condition

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Consider the following table:

```
              date       mainMode       freq
  7     1560327222            CAR          3
165     1560327508        WALKING          1
 28     1560327306            CAR          1
 35     1560326894            CAR          1
184     1560327408            CAR          2
```

I would like to keep the table ordered by the `freq` column in descending order, but the first row must always be the most recent one based on the `date`column. The idea would be to move the most recent one to the first row, not copy it or inserting the same duplicated file, but move it to the first position, avoiding to duplicate it.

The expected result would be:

```
              date       mainMode       freq
 35     1560326894            CAR          1
  7     1560327222            CAR          3
184     1560327408            CAR          2
165     1560327508        WALKING          1
 28     1560327306            CAR          1
```

**EDIT**

The goal would be to sort the table based on `freq`, and then take the most recent record (a single row) and move it to the first row position of the dataframe without duplicating it. I hope this helps understanding the issue.

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: Here with sample data working `df = df.sort_values('freq', ascending=False)`. Is possible change sample data for [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: hi @jezrael. I'll edit the question

Comment: Can you change data?

Comment: I did my best, since i don't have a lot of data available for this example

Comment: Super, data are now perfect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) with select first value with min, then select all another rows with `sort_values`:

```
#select all rows with min date
m = df['date'] == df['date'].min()

df = pd.concat([df[m], df[~m].sort_values('freq', ascending=False)])
print (df)
           date mainMode  freq
35   1560326894      CAR     1
7    1560327222      CAR     3
184  1560327408      CAR     2
165  1560327508  WALKING     1
28   1560327306      CAR     1
```

Or:

```
#select index value by first minimal date
i = df['date'].idxmin()

df = pd.concat([df.loc[[i]], df[df.index != i].sort_values('freq', ascending=False)])
print (df)
           date mainMode  freq
35   1560326894      CAR     1
7    1560327222      CAR     3
184  1560327408      CAR     2
165  1560327508  WALKING     1
28   1560327306      CAR     1
```

Comment: Thanks again jezrael. As always your help is awesome :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you want.

```
df.sort_values(by='freq',ascending=False,inplace=True)
```

Comment: this is not what i need, i need to  move the most recent row to the first position. In future cases it will be possible to have more rows with different `freq` values, but the highest freq value will not necessarily be in the first position. Is not as simple as to order the df.

I need a conditional that puts in the first row the most recent record, and the rest should be ordered by the `freq`value

Comment: I think u need to change ur example or data